# Преобразовать строку в массив с разделением чисел и знаков операций

Tags: javascript, строки

Как преобразовать строку например

```
var str="55+7777-1/9.1777*2"
```

`str.split("")`-разбивает по символам а мне нужно чтоб любое количество цифр подряд  было одним элементом массива, и чтоб на выходе получился вот такой массив

```
str=["55","+","7777","-","1","/","9.1777","*","2"]
```

Comment: регуляркой парсить нужно

Comment: у меня с регулярными выражениями получается не очень ((

Comment: к несчастью у меня сними тоже туго, иначе, будьте уверены я бы написал вам готовый вариант)

 как вариант еще можно парсить строку по символьно и проверять не цифра ли это или '.' если да подклеивать в переменную и как только  появиться что то не похожее на цифру  добавлять ее в массив , обнулять и начинать сначала, в случае с НЕ цифрами тоже самое только ждать  прихода цифры

Comment: но регуляркой куда как лучше и чище вот внизу кажется есть рабочий вариант

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var str="55+7777-1/9.1777*2+.8"
console.log(str.match(/\.\d+|\d+\.?\d*|./g));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: не понимаю почему знаки попали в результат, если не перечислены)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `|.`

Comment: @MedvedevDev а, ну да

Comment: а вот если число минусовое как сделать чтоб было например не["-","55","+"..........] а ["-55","+"...........]

Comment: @xlabuchik, а не надо так делать. Это не число, а унарный минус. `var a = { 12: 7, 13.8: 42 }` - так можно, а так `var b = { -1: 9 }` - нельзя. [Тут в комментариях](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988) есть примеры для разных языков доказывающие, что запись вида `-7` не является литералом.

Comment: @xlabuchik, обновил ответ для поддержки чисел вида `.8`.

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Кажется будет как-то так:

```js
var str = "55+7777-1/9.1777*2";
var result = str.match( /\d+|\+|\-|\*|\//g);
console.log(result);
```

**[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** - возвращает получившиеся совпадения при сопоставлении строки с регулярным выражением.

---

Хотя на счет `9.1777` - непонятно куда относить. Поэтому пока оно не попало никуда

Answer (score 2):

Регуляркой:

```
"55+7777-1/9.1777*2".match(/[.\d]+|[^.\d]/g);
```

Вернёт..

```
Array [ "55", "+", "7777", "-", "1", "/", "9.1777", "*", "2" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```js
console.log("55+7777-1/9.1777*2".split(/([0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*)/).filter(Boolean));
```